# CollectionView size is wrong when presented as a popover segue until dataReload

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uipopovercontroller

I have a segue set up in my Storyboard as "Present as Popover". The destinationViewController is a UICollectionViewController embedded in a NavigationController. When the Popover view loads, my collectionView reports it's size as basically the full size of the iPad window. However, once  I call `[self.collectionView reloadData]`, the collectionView correctly sees it's size as the size of the popoverViewController. Here is what I'm using to size the collectionViewCell (it's based on the size of the collectionView)

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize collectionViewBounds = collectionView.bounds.size; //768x1004 when the Popover is first loaded
                                                             //400x644 after reloadData is called
    int navigationHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    int toolbarHeight = self.navigationController.toolbar.bounds.size.height;
    int statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    int cellHeight = collectionViewBounds.height - (navigationHeight + statusBarHeight + toolbarHeight);
    int cellWidth = collectionViewBounds.width;
    return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
}
```

I tried manually setting `CGSize collectionViewBounds` to the size that I set the popoverView, but then my data wasn't loaded into the collectionViewCell until I did a dataReload and this function stopped working also:

```
- (void) snapToCellAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)index withAnimation:(BOOL) animated
{
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:index atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:animated];
}
```

Instead of snapping to `index`, the collectionView scrolled between two cells with no data loaded. This is fine though as I don't want to hard code any dimensions, so my main focus right now is to get the initial load to size correctly.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.